# How to send this post request and receive JSON data using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, json, api, post

I want to send this particular post request using asp.net and receive json data as string.
$ http POST :9000/api/auth Username="admin" Password="adminpassword"
Pls help me out here...

Comment: ...by writing some code. Seriously. This is a coding website, what have you tried? There are tutorials by the dozen for asp.net, including examples with JSON data, receiving from ajax requests etc. This is not an unusual requirement, you just need to read a bit and try something. This site isn't a free write-my-code service, and the volunteers here will generally not give up their time for that, especially when the subject is common and you appear to have done nothing at all to help yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ASP.NET Web API to create an API which receives the request and sends the response as a string. You can read about it here : https://www.asp.net/web-api.

An sample example would be to create a class similar to the one below :-

```
public class authController: ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string Test(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        return "Received auth request from " + UserName;
    }
}
```

The Test Method can now be accessed by going to http://localhost:9000/api/auth/login and passing the UserName and Password Parameter.